# QGIS select multiple features by value

Tags: qgis, select

I have a polygon layer and every polygon has a unique gml_id. I want to select multiple at the same time. Normaly I use **selection by expression** and it works very well. I fount the tool **select by value** and wonder how it works to select multiple features.

Different inputs that doesn't work
[image]

[image]

I´ve tried different spellings in the input mask, but it doesn't work.
What is the correct synthax?

This is my "select by expression"
[image]

I use the QGIS Version 3.4.8 LTR

Comment: Add some single quotation marks around your values, then try again.

Comment: What happens if you type just `DESNALK0h` (i.e. no `OR`)?

Comment: Single quotations or omitting the 'or' doesn´t help

Comment: Try using `"gml_id" IN ('DESNALK...', …)`